# optimal indicator function on a grid

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, dynamic-programming

Consider the grid $X =\{ 0,1,\ldots,m-1\}\times \{ 0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ of size $m \times n$. An indicator function $f:X\mapsto \{ 0,1\}$ on this grid is defined to be monotonic, if
$ i\leq s, j \leq t \Rightarrow f_{i,j} \leq f_{s,t} , \; \forall i,j,s,t \in X $.
We are also given a function $v : X \mapsto [0,1]$ such that $\sum_{i,j}v_{i,j}=1$, and another function $b : X \mapsto [0,1]$. I want to find the  monotonic indicator function $f$ that maximizes
$$ \sum_{i,j} v_{i,j}\; b_{i,j}\;f_{i,j} 
$$ subject to the condition
$$  
%\frac{ \mathrm{Tr}(v^\mathrm{T}f)}{ \mathrm{Tr}(b^\mathrm{T}f)}=
\frac{\sum_{i,j}  v_{i,j} \; f_{i,j}}{\sum_{i,j} v_{i,j} \; b_{i,j} \;  f_{i,j}}  < c$$ for some specified positive constant $c$. How can I perform this optimization?

A brute force search is impractical as there are $\binom{m+n}{m}$ possible monotonic indicator functions. I'm wondering if there is a DP solution. If there are not fast solutions, what are some heuristic approaches? Another approach I thought of is to convert this into a continuous optimization problem by smoothening $b$, but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: This is essentially a binary linear program. Is that not an acceptable approach?